# How to write this variable belongs to domain of set or array

Tags: cplex, opl

I want to declare that

```
int NNN =...; 
range N =1..NNN;
int BBB =...; 
range B =1..BBB;
int EX1 [N]; 
int EX2 [B];     
execute 
{for( var i in N)
EX1 [i] = i;
}
execute 
{for( var i in B)
EX2 [i] belongs to  EX1};
```

So how to define that each value of EX2 belongs to set of Ex1?

Answer (score 0):

```
int NNN =4; 
range N =1..NNN;
int BBB =3; 
range B =1..BBB;
int EX1 [i in N]=i; 
dvar int EX2 [B] in N;     

subject to
{
  
}
```

works fine

And with regards to your latest comment

```
int Npol=2;
int NNN =4; 
range N =1..NNN;
int BBB =3; 
range B =1..BBB;
int EX1 [i in N]=i; 
dvar int EX2 [B] in N;  
dvar int EX3 [B] in N;  
dvar int EX4 [B] in N;     

subject to
{
  forall(i in B) EX2[i] == Npol* EX3[i]-EX4[i];
}
```

works fine too

Comment: Thank you dr. after defining EX2 as a decision variable i want to use it in an equation i wrote this   :::::       Int Npol=2; execute    
                                                                                                                         
        {       
         for( var i in B)
         EX2[i] = Npol* EX3[i]-EX4[i];  
    }        this gives me scribting runtime error: cannot convert to a number , "[ alloNumVar"].     as each of Ex1 and Ex2 and Ex3 and Ex4 are defined as dvar as you said , so how to solve this?

Comment: I am grateful to you, Thank you. is there any communication method rather than here  like whats app or something else? thanks in advance

Comment: As mentioned at https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/low-barrier-entry-optimization-through-cplex-alex-fleischer/ you can use support and forums

Comment: Than you dr. is it valid to make domain from an array not a range like    dvar int Ex4[b] in [another array] ?

Comment: Yes. See example https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoodomain.mod in https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-decision-optimization-simple-alex-fleischer/

Comment: Dear Dr. Alex. How to check the condition of any constrain whether the constrain is true or false cause i have boolean decision variable which force one of the two constrains to work how to check this? thanks in advance